# Is there a training/validation split happening internally, or is there just one training set and testing set?

Tags: machine-learning, split, neural-network, pytorch, evaluation

so recently I've been following the tutorial in https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html and I came up with the following question: is there a training/validation split happening internally?

The thing is, in this tutorial, the main dataset is spliced into training and testing. Here, the training set is used for training and the testing in the evaluate() function.

To my knowledge, when dealing with neural networks usually the data is split into 3 sets: training, validation and testing. In this tutorial though, it is only split into training and testing. For what I know, usually the model is trained and then evaluated, and the weights are then updated according to what was learnt in the evaluation step. However, I can't seem to find any connection between the evaluate function and training. Therefore, in this example the model is being evaluated AND tested using the same dataset.

Is there something here that I might be missing? Is there an internal split of the training dataset happening during training (into training and validation) and the function evaluate() is simply used for testing the performance of the model?

````
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        # train for one epoch, printing every 10 iterations
        train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, data_loader, device, epoch, print_freq=10)
        # update the learning rate
        lr_scheduler.step()
        # evaluate on the test dataset
        evaluate(model, data_loader_test, device=device)```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a training/validation split happening internally?
>
> Is there an internal split of the training dataset happening during
> training (into training and validation) and the function evaluate() is
> simply used for testing the performance of the model?

No, you are not missing anything. What you see is exactly what's being done there. **There is no internal splitting happening.** It's just an example to show how something is done in pytorch without cluttering it unncessarily.

Some datasets such as `CIFAR10/CIFAR100`, come only with a train/test set and usually it has been **the norm** to just train and then evaluate on the test set in examples. However, nothing stops you from splitting the training set however you like, it's up to you. In such tutorials they just tried to keep everything as simple as possible.

Comment: So can I then assume that during training the data is being internally split for training and validation? And then at the evaluation step, another dataset (in this case data_loader_test) is being used?

Comment: No, during training, only training set is fed into the network. during evaluation only the testset specified is fed into the network.

Comment: Hmm okay, the thing is that in order to evaluate the performance of the network, as far as I know two metrics are necessary: training loss and validation loss. This train_one_epoch() function only returns a dictionary containing the losses on the training set, and evaluate() just returns average precision and recall. Therefore, I am struggling at obtaining the validation loss on the validation set, since I cannot seem to find this anywhere.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. Are you talking about this very detection example or network training in general? if its in the general sense, nothing stops you from showing the losses. Are you looking for the `train_one_epoch` implementation? you can view its implementation and if you'd want alter it according to your needs [engine.py](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/references/detection/engine.py).

Comment: I am talking about network training in general, since based on this tutorial I have built my own detector for my Bachelor's thesis (based on industrial datasets). Here, the train_one_epoch function only returns losses during training (I have already checked the implementation), but I am also trying to somehow get the losses during validation.

Comment: Then simply calculate the loss in validation as well. whats stopping you from doing that?

Comment: I have no idea how to do this. In the evaluate() function the metrics will be given, and I have no idea how to calculate the loss in the validation set.

Comment: I dont see any argument concerning metrics in evaluate() argument list! just look at the training, its the same procedure!

Comment: Okay, I just found another someone else with the same problem and I solved it by passing the data loader with the validation set to the function train_one_epoch and running the model with no gradients.

Comment: OK then please accept the answer if it answered your question so this is marked as completed.